# How can I set linear/angular velocity without using keyframes?

Tags: physics

I want some objects to be physically simulated. I want to specify their initial linear and angular velocities and let that evolve for infinity frames, rather than keyframing position and rotation parameters.

I would like this to be a parameter that I can fiddle with continuously independently of framerate. Extrapolating between two keyframes is not a good solution because I will need to recalculate the first delta each time I either change the speed of the object or the framerate (which will vary between renders).

How can I do this?